# MATLAB: Repeatedly run function with multiple variables

Tags: function, matlab, batch-file

I have a function which calculates image texture (using 2D convolution via NLFILTER):

```
y=imagetexture(image,winsize)
```

In my matlab workspace I have 3 variables; the red green and blue bands of an image (r,g,b).
How can I repeatedly run this function on each band (r,g,b) for various window sizes?
e.g. 3x3,5x5,7x7 etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your red, green and blue image bands were stored in variables `r`, `g`, and `b`, would this do what you need?

```
winsizes = [3, 5, 7];

for i = 1:numel(winsizes)
    yr{i} = imagetexture(r, winsizes(i));
    yg{i} = imagetexture(g, winsizes(i));
    yb{i} = imagetexture(b, winsizes(i));
end
```

Comment: Yes that's worked, thanks! Just one more thing; How do I get the individual layers out of the cell variable it creates?

Comment: If you've run the code above, then to put the results for the red band with window size 3 into its own array, you could say something like red3 = yr{1}.